# How does one load data into the local Development Server using Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know this is covered amply in the GAE help site.  It's not working out for me.  I'm a little **green** on Python.  But I also know how imports work. The entities module is right there in the same folder with the loader.  So what are the GAE scripts doing?

Here's my loader:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
import entities

class CardLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'Card',
            [('english', str),
            ('translation', str)
            ])

loaders = [CardLoader]
```

Here is what is in a file called entities.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Card(db.Model):
    english = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    translation = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Here's a snip of what's in the .csv

```
"cardId","english","translation"
"3994","face","la cara"
"4027","art","el arte"
```

My version of Python:

```
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Here's my command (on Windows):

> python "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py"
>   upload_data --config_file=card_loader.py --url
>   http://localhost:8080/remote_api --filename=card_data.csv --kind=Card

Here's the output:

```
Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20110723.183520
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Please enter login credentials for localhost:8080
Email: admin
Password for admin:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 76, in <module
>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 72, in run_fil
e
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 3708, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 3699, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 2345, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 3484, in __call__
    return method()
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 3311, in PerformUpload
    run_fn(args)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.p
y", line 3202, in RunBulkloader
    sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict))
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 4369, in Run
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 4180, in _PerformBulkload
    LoadConfig(config_file)
  File "c:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkload
er.py", line 3844, in LoadConfig
    ('', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE))
  File "card_loader.py", line 3, in <module>
    import entities
ImportError: No module named entities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback describes a `ImportError`: the module `entities` wasn't found. Is that where your models are? If so, you must be sure it can be found (add its directory to `sys.path` if needed).

Comment: It's actually in the local path.  Does appcfg.py act differently on windows?  I'll try the FQ path.

Comment: I had to do this: import sys
import os
_root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, _root_dir)
import entities